# What is the political proposal of Emmanuel Macron?

Tags: presidential-election, france

I have to admit that not being French, I have not paid too close attention to the various proposals of the different presidential candidates. Now that the second turn draws near, I'd like to understand a bit better what are the proposed policies of Macron.

I have read that he is more moderate than Fillon, putting him, in my understanding, towards the center. Nevertheless, some French friend told me that it is incorrect and I should consider him a right-winger, even if not as extreme as FN.

What are the concrete positions/ideas of Macron? Within the context of European politics, where does he stand?

Comment: His political proposal is "to do a barrage against FN fachism". That pretty much sums it all, unfortunately. People are not going to vote for him, but against FN, just like they voted against Sarkozy 5 years ago (and whoever replaced him didn't matter).

Comment: @Bregalad well, since he won the first round not only against FN I was expecting him to have said something to convince enough people that he was better than all the others, not only FN

Comment: @Bregalad That's actually not what he has been saying. For better or for worse, and whatever else he might say or not say about his policies, he has very deliberately stayed clear from such rhetoric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, his main policies are to implement a "€50bn (£43bn) public investment plan for job-training, shift to renewable energy, infrastructure and modernisation" and also implement a "big cut in corporation tax and leeway for companies to renegotiate 35-hour week".

> Policies: Remake the “failed” and “vacuous” French political system; relax labour laws; cut business taxes; reform unemployment system; encourage social mobility; cut public spending (but boost investment); shrink public sector; reduce number of MPs; establish eurozone government; hire 10,000 more police and gendarmes.
>
> <sup>Source: [The Guardian - Emmanuel Macron v Marine Le Pen: who are they and what are their policies?](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/apr/23/france-presidential-le-pen-macron-melenchon-fillon-first-round-vote)</sup>

---

> What Macron wants:
>
> - €50bn (£43bn) public investment plan for job-training, shift to renewable energy, infrastructure and modernisation
> - Reimbursement of full cost of glasses, dentures and hearing aids
> - Big cut in corporation tax and leeway for companies to renegotiate 35-hour week
> - Cut in jobless rate to 7% (now 9.7%)
> - Ban on mobile use in schools for under-15s and a €500 culture 
>     pass for 18-year-olds
>
> <sup>Source: [BBC - Emmanuel Macron: The meteoric rise of France's youngest presidential candidate](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-sh/emmanuel_macron)</sup>

---

### Other proposed policies mentioned by Macron

- local housing tax exemptions worth 10 billion euros ($10.6 billion)
- reimbursement of the full cost of cultural shows, dentures and hearing aids
- cuts in social welfare levies for low earners coupled with tax breaks for their employers
- merger of myriad public- and private-sector retirement pension systems
- merger of unemployment benefit systems, which currently differ for regular wage-earners and the self-employed
- keeping France's budget deficit below the EU-mandated 3 percent of GDP
- lowering the jobless rate to 7 percent by the end of his potential five-year term from around 10 percent now
- an investment plan of 50 billion euros and public spending savings seen reaching 60 billion annually by the end of the mandate
- corporate tax would be cut from 33 to 25 percent
- CICE tax credit system for firms would be converted into permanent payroll tax breaks for low-wage workers
- 35-hour legal work week would remain but negotiation of real work hours would be left to company level.
- low-wage earners would be exempted from certain social welfare levies, a measure that would put an extra month's wage per year in the employee's pocket

<sup>Source: [Reuters - Factbox: Emmanuel Macron's presidential election policies](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-france-election-macron-programme-fact-idUSKBN17G19H)</sup>